# Generate random string in .tpl file

Tags: php, html, validation, smarty

I have the following input field:

```
<input name="domain" value="{$domain}" size="50" 
data-hostname-check="{$options}" 
onchange="if (
typeof simulateCart == 'function' && this.checkValidity())
simulateCart.call(this);"/>
```

What i need is to generate a random string for if the input field when its not filled. But I have no clue how to do this. This input field is in an if loop using smarty template.

The onchange is required at the moment so if I remove this you can leave the input field blank but there should be a label before we can insert it into the database.

Comment: Is it possible to pass some dummy data as `$domain` if it is empty when calling the template? This seems like a bad place to manage default values.

Comment: You wish that the field be filled when the user leave this blank or when your page was be generated?

Comment: @AndersonAndrade correct it should be auto generated when the field is leaved blank by the user!

Answer (score 2):

It *sounds* like you're looking for a simple PHP `echo` in the **[`placeholder` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder)**.

I've gone with `substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 7)` to generate a random lowercase alphabetic string in the following, but feel free to adapt to suit:

```
<input name="domain" value="{$domain}" size="50" 
data-hostname-check="{$options}"
placeholder="<?php echo substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 7); ?>"
onchange="if (
typeof simulateCart == 'function' && this.checkValidity())
simulateCart.call(this);"/>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for the help. Will the echo work inside the tpl file ? What should i change in order to create a string name like test{randomstring}.local

Comment: it still askes for the hostname to fill in.